# Solve performance issues for MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

I have a query. It has an index but I'm not sure why it's taking time for fewer rows. Can anyone please suggest to improving that query performance?

```
SELECT 
  up.id post_id, 
  c.id community_id, 
  SUBSTRING(up.description, 1, 30) post_description, 
  c.name community_name, 
  c.is_index is_index, 
  c.slug slug, 
  p.last_modified_on last_modified_on, 
  c.is_shop is_shop 
FROM 
  user_post up 
  INNER JOIN community c ON up.community_id = c.id 
  and c.is_index = 1 
  inner join participant pa on c.participant_id = pa.id 
  and pa.is_active = 1 
  inner join participating_entity p on up.participating_entity_id = p.id 
  left join indexed_post ip on ip.user_post_id = up.id 
  and ip.is_active = 1 
WHERE 
  p.is_active = 1 
  and up.is_spam_post = 0 
  and ip.id is null 
  and LENGTH(up.description) >= 20 
order by 
  up.id 
limit 
  358223, 
  5000\G
```

row scans:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: c
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,fk_community_participant1_idx,idx_is_index_participant_id
          key: idx_is_index_participant_id
      key_len: 2
          ref: const
         rows: 6702
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: pa
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 8
          ref: she.c.participant_id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 10.00
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: up
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: fk_user_post_community1_idx,fk_user_post_entity1_idx,is_spam_post,idx_is_spam_post,idx_community_id_participating_entity_id_is_spam_post,idx_participating_entity_id_community_id
          key: idx_community_id_participating_entity_id_is_spam_post
      key_len: 9
          ref: she.c.id
         rows: 338
     filtered: 50.00
        Extra: Using index condition; Using where
*************************** 4. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: ip
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: idx_user_post_id
          key: idx_user_post_id
      key_len: 8
          ref: she.up.id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 10.00
        Extra: Using where; Not exists
*************************** 5. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: p
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,idx_is_active
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 8
          ref: she.up.participating_entity_id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 50.00
        Extra: Using where
```

It takes more than 15 seconds. Can anyone please suggest what is the problem? Can't it be solved by rewriting the query to increase the performance?

data output:

```
*************************** 5000. row ***************************
         post_id: 1788267
    community_id: 492
post_description: #none #FoodParty
  community_name: Cooking, Food, Recipes and More...
        is_index: 1
            slug: cooking-food-recipes-and-more
last_modified_on: 2020-03-09 17:48:50
         is_shop: 0
5000 rows in set (2 min 13.05 sec)
```

Table structure;

```
Table : Community

PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_community_participant1_idx` (`participant_id`),
  KEY `fk_community_community_type1_idx` (`community_type_id`),
  KEY `idx_parent_participant_id` (`parent_participant_id`),
  KEY `idx_score_latest` (`score_latest`),
  KEY `slug` (`slug`(191)),
  KEY `idx_is_index_participant_id` (`is_index`,`participant_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `_fk_community_community_type1` FOREIGN KEY (`community_type_id`) REFERENCES `community_type` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `_fk_community_participant1` FOREIGN KEY (`participant_id`) REFERENCES `participant` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION


Table : participant

*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: participant
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `participant` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `participant_type_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `crdt` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_modified_on` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_modified_by` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `is_deleted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `partner_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sheroes_deep_link` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_participant_participation_type1_idx` (`participant_type_id`),
  KEY `idx_participant_last_modified_on` (`last_modified_on`),
  KEY `idx_participant_crdt` (`crdt`),
  KEY `sheroes_deep_link` (`sheroes_deep_link`(191)),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_participant_participation_type1` FOREIGN KEY (`participant_type_id`) REFERENCES `participant_type` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION

Table: participating_entity

PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_entity_entity_type_idx` (`entity_type_id`),
  KEY `idx_participating_entity_last_modified_on` (`last_modified_on`),
  KEY `created_by` (`created_by`),
  KEY `fk_partner_id_idx` (`partner_id`),
  KEY `crdt` (`crdt`),
  KEY `idx_category` (`category`),
  KEY `idx_created_by` (`created_by`),
  KEY `idx_is_active` (`is_active`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_entity_entity_type` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_type_id`) REFERENCES `entity_type` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_partner_id` FOREIGN KEY (`partner_id`) REFERENCES `api_consumer_partner` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION

Table : indexed_post

*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: indexed_post
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `indexed_post` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_post_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `crdt` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_modified_by` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_modified_on` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_user_post_id` (`user_post_id`)

Table : user_post

PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_user_post_users1_idx` (`users_id`),
  KEY `fk_user_post_community1_idx` (`community_id`),
  KEY `fk_user_post_entity1_idx` (`participating_entity_id`),
  KEY `idx_source_ent_id` (`source_entity_id`),
  KEY `idx_entity_start_dt` (`entity_start_date`),
  KEY `idx_rating_for_company` (`rating`),
  KEY `user_post_source_type` (`source_type`),
  KEY `is_spam_post` (`is_spam_post`),
  KEY `idx_is_spam_post` (`is_spam_post`),
  KEY `idx_is_theme_post` (`is_theme_post`),
  KEY `idx_meta_title` (`meta_title`),
  KEY `idx_meta_description` (`meta_description`),
  KEY `idx_recipient_id` (`recipient_id`),
  KEY `idx_title` (`title`(191)),
  KEY `idx_community_id_participating_entity_id_is_spam_post` (`community_id`,`participating_entity_id`,`is_spam_post`),
  KEY `user_post_is_recommended_IDX` (`is_recommended`),
  KEY `idx_participating_entity_id_community_id` (`participating_entity_id`,`community_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `__fk_user_post_community1` FOREIGN KEY (`community_id`) REFERENCES `community` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `__fk_user_post_entity1` FOREIGN KEY (`participating_entity_id`) REFERENCES `participating_entity` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `__fk_user_post_users1` FOREIGN KEY (`users_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

Comment: the onl thing you can do is trying to use different combined INDEX , and see if they work better, as rule of thumb all WHERE columns and ON columns should be in a combined index, but you must check different indexes to be sure

Comment: does this have any rewrite possibilities ?

Comment: When asking query performance question always include `EXPLAIN` and `CREATE TABLE` statements

Comment: the above query has 5 tables so that's why I haven't posted it, but the index name is the same as in the query.

Comment: a SHOW CREATE TABLE will show all column with all indexes, there is no easy way to get the "best" perfomace you have to try as i said different indexes

Comment: can you please suggest that index?

Comment: let me share the structure of the table

Comment: `LEFT JOIN ip ON ... ip.x = 1` turns is really `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing can fix

```
limit  358223, 5000
```

That query must join all those tables, filter out the unnecessary rows, sort them, *skip over 358223 rows* and finally deliver 5000.

If you are dumping a million rows, either

- Dump them all at once, so you are not rebuilding the set over and over.
- "Remember where you left off" so you don't have to perform `OFFSET`.  However, because of all the complexity in the query, I doubt if this is possible.

So, in my opinion, the real cure is to rethink *why* you need this query.

Note that each table needs to test for `is_active`.  This effective prevents some optimizations.

Comment: i have shared the (data) along with explain plan please check and give me some possible performance optimisation @Rick James.

please check the o/p

Comment: @skyler - Please explain the need for the LIMIT and OFFSET.

Comment: so do i have to remove the limit function @Rick James

Comment: i don't know about that it's from application side query.

Comment: if i remove the limit means does it will be optimised ?

Comment: @skyler - The query, with or without the LIMIT, is looking at thousands, maybe millions, of rows.  What is the goal (in English) of the query?  Maybe we can think of some other way to achieve a _similar_ goal more efficiently.  (There is no hope for the query as it stands.)

Comment: I'm not sure what is the goal for this either I have said already it's from the application side query and I don't what they actually trying to fetch it sad for this query anyways if it has no hope means thank you for all this long :) @Ricky James

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the following?

```
SELECT 
  up.id post_id, 
  c.id community_id, 
  SUBSTRING(up.description, 1, 30) post_description, 
  c.name community_name, 
  c.is_index is_index, 
  c.slug slug, 
  p.last_modified_on last_modified_on, 
  c.is_shop is_shop 
FROM 
  user_post up 
  INNER JOIN community c ON up.community_id = c.id AND up.is_spam_post = 0 and c.is_index = 1 AND  LENGTH(up.description) >= 20 
  inner join participant pa on c.participant_id = pa.id and pa.is_active = 1 
  inner join participating_entity p on up.participating_entity_id = p.id AND   p.is_active = 1 
  left join indexed_post ip on ip.user_post_id = up.id and ip.is_active = 1 
WHERE 
   ip.id is null 
order by 
  up.id 
limit 
  358223, 
  5000\G
```

Comment: sorry the above one is taking time to execute

Comment: Sometimes 'Inner Join' work better than 'Where' clauses, but it always depends on the database engine. In other words I am not sure if my query above will make the query faster but there is a chance to it.